# Submitted to jounal status average time

Tags: paper-submission

What is the average time for a manuscript status to stay " submitted to journal" in elsevier? I submitted over 2 weeks ago and still no change, this has never happened with me before, usually status changes to with editor after afew days. Other colleagues who have previous experience with the same journal say it usually takes afew days. Does anyone have a similar experience with elsevier? When do i send an email to request a status update?